# jquery.serialScroll not working

Tags: jquery, serialscroll

I am having issues with `jquery.serialScroll` not working in my case.

I have a div `id=ticker` which basically works like a scrolling ticker. something like this - http://www.tinymassive.com/ (whats happening section). So i am prepending dynamic content to div `id=ticker`, and I want scrolling animation from top-to-bottom as shown in the link.

```
$('#ticker').serialScroll({
                    items:'div',
                    duration:50000,
                    force:false,
                    axis:'y',
                    easing:'linear',
                    lazy:true,
                    interval:1, 
                    step:2 
                    });
```

Dont think the above code is working, even if i comment i see no change in the behavior.

The div `id=ticker` is contained in another div which is contained in another div, basically think of it like 4-5 level tree like structure

> body -> div[id=wrapper] -> div[class=main] -> div[class=content] ->
>   div[class=frame] -> div[class=bg] -> div[class=primary-content] ->
>   div[id=ticker]

Heres the css...

```
#wrapper {
 width: 942px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.main{
 width:942px;
 margin:163px 0 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.content{
 background:url(../images/content-bg.gif) repeat-y;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:662px;
 float:left;
}

.frame{
 background:url(../images/frame-bg.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
 width:662px;
}

.bg{
 background:url(../images/bg-bg.gif) no-repeat 0 100%;
 width:662px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.primary-content{
 padding: 12px 20px 40px 22px;
 width:620px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#ticker {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also if it helps - the ticker div contains a list of `div[class=breadcrumps]`, which i am trying to scroll

```
.breadcrumbs{
 border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;
 padding:6px 0 6px 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 clear:both;
}
```

What i see is - i see the items getting prepended, but dont see the animation/effects. In fact the .serialScroll does not seem to have any affect at all.

I have included the following js files.
- jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js
- jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js
- and obviously jquery 142

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.